# How to properly bring only updated files from a github repo

Tags: git, github

I've just starting to use git and github.
I checked in my new app from my dev machine.
On my test machine, I already have a copy of the code, but that copy was cp'd to it, and did not go through git.
What is the proper way to keep the test machine's code in sync with my github changes?

Comment: Does the copy have a `.git` directory? If yes, you can directly do a `git pull` in that directory (which also happens to be an entire git repo itself) on the test machine.

Comment: no, it did not. in fact, I'm going to do a git clone on my test machine, so everything is set up properly from the beginning

Comment: Here's a similar SU question that already documents it: http://superuser.com/q/315398 (basically, as long as you copy the entire thing, including `.git`, you can just use it as a git repo and do pulls etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you effectively have some branch tip checked out in your test directory, but no underlying repo for it,

```
git clone --no-checkout u://r/l ../wip # fetch just the repo, leave worktree as-is
mv ../wip/.git .                       # move the repo here

git symbolic-ref HEAD $thatbranch   # set a refname for the worktree content
git read-tree HEAD                  # load the default worktree index from there
git update-index --refresh          # get its metadata up to date
```

The index refresh will tell you which if any files in the worktree don't match what the index says, and you haven't touched your worktree at all so you can lather-rinse-repeat until you find what commit is closest to what's already out.  You could even reorder things,

```
git read-tree $thatbranch
git update-index --refresh
```

and only when it turns out you've loaded up the right one or near enough

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD $thatbranch
```